# How can I implement jsbindings in cocos2d-iPhone v3?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

In cocos2d-iPhone v2.1, there was a built-in jsbindings feature. I can do all the animation in a main.js file.

But in cocos2d-iPhone v3 by now(rc2), they haven't implemented this feature. I need this feature in v3. So I want to know how to add this feature by my self?

It seems that Zynga's jsbindings project in GitHub is the right way. But I can't manage it under their instruction. Someone help?

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cocos2d-iphone v3 does not and will not have Javascript bindings.

If you require to use the JS bindings stick to cocos2d-iphone v2 and wrap up your existing project with it. But keep in mind that the JS bindings in v2 are no longer in active development (haven't been for about 6 months now) and support will be limited.

Yes, the [JSBindings](https://github.com/zynga/jsbindings) project provides what you need - feel free to ask another question with the specific problems you have setting it up. But the project does require you to create and customise the bindings which probably doesn't justify using it for a small team / single person. There are better solutions to do native web development, even those where you can deploy to both web and html.

One alternative (among many) is to consider porting to cocos2d-x where the JS bindings continue to be more actively supported through the cocos2d-html5 project. This may be easiest considering your already have cocos2d-ish code. But if you can start from scratch I would advice looking at the plethora of native JS engines out there.

Comment: Thanks Steffen. Thank you for telling me the schedule of Cocos2d-iPhone v3 on Javascript bindings. I'm working on an iOS app rendering animation by loading animation script from remote server. So maybe I need to stick on Cocos2d-iPhone v2.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D It seems like Cocos2d is putting a lot more effort into their JS/HTML5 frameworks. Assume and I'm starting from scracth and my goal is a cross platform (web and native mobile) solution: Would you still recommend starting on an alternative JS engine? Or is Cocos2d a viable option at this point in time (are they trying to be an alternative to the industry standards already out there)?

Comment: Personally I would not consider web + native mobile as desirable cross-platform targets. Web and mobile are so very different in many aspects, user interface, user expectations, design, etc. that the technology allowing this kind of development really becomes just a minor consideration, and using two native engines isn't a real hindrance. Especially not if you design the app so that any game logic has no dependencies on the engine/renderer.